# Using jQuery UI Layout plugin with Liferay

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, liferay, liferay-6

I used [jQuery UI](http://layout.jquery-dev.com) to create basic layout with 3 resizable panels. I would like to use this layout in Liferay 6.2.

[Basic layout](http://jsfiddle.net/vLeve252/)

In **liferay-portlet.xml** I included all css and js files.

```
    <header-portlet-css>/styles/layout-default.css</header-portlet-css>
    <header-portlet-css>/styles/main.css</header-portlet-css>
    <header-portlet-javascript>/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js</header-portlet-javascript>
    <header-portlet-javascript>/scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js</header-portlet-javascript>
    <header-portlet-javascript>/scripts/jquery.layout.min-1.3.0.js</header-portlet-javascript>
    <footer-portlet-javascript>/scripts/set.layout.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
```

**set.layout.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

      // OUTER-LAYOUT
      $('#mainLayout').layout({
        center__paneSelector: "#rightPanel",
        west__paneSelector:   "#filter",
          west__size: 250,
        // MIDDLE-LAYOUT (child of outer-center-pane)
        center__childOptions: {
          center__paneSelector: "#graph",
          south__paneSelector:  "#details",
          south__size:      250
        }
      });

});
```

**index.jsp** content is basically similar to html content in jsfiddle snippet. I don't get any errors in browser console log or tomcat logs, but layout is not rendered correctly. Bottom part of layout is missing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you remove your jQuery ui layout and replace it with some other elements does your html element still only fill part of the window?  Can you host your site somewhere and provide a link?

Comment: Yes, also without jQuery ui layout plugin main layout fill only part of the window, because of Liferay. I can't host my portal, but can provide .war file https://www.dropbox.com/s/kec9l1hs5acn89s/jqUI-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a css issue, have you tried setting the Height of your Html/body to 100% ?

CSS

```
html {
    height:100%;
}
```

or if that doesn't work

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, I tried it, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Matt can you get your site online so that I can see it?

Comment: I am sorry, but i can't host portal.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't set height of #mainLayout div and realize this because of Trevor's answer.